# Need object setup before multiple unit tests are run

Tags: java, testing, junit, selenium-webdriver

At the moment I have the following code:

```
public class AlterServiceSelT  
{

    @Before
    public void setupAndActivate()
    {
        System.out.println("setupAndActivate");
    }

    @Test
    public void suspendService()
    {
        System.out.println("suspendService");
    }

    @Test
    public void reActivateService()
    {
        System.out.println("reActivateService");
    }

    @After
    public void terminateService()
    {
        System.out.println("terminateService");
    }
}
```

and when ran I get the following in my console:

```
setupAndActivate
reActivateService
terminateService
setupAndActivate
suspendService
terminateService
```

The problem is that the full code for setupAndActivate() takes 15 minutes and its output is needed to run for the tests. Ideally I would like the console to output:

```
setupAndActivate
reActivateService
suspendService
terminateService
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at `@BeforeClass` in stead of using the `@Before`.

One of the downsides of `BeforeClass` is that it has to be defined on a static method, so all your fields that you set up have to be static.

Upside is that your setup is only done once for all the tests in your class.

Are you sure that a setup of 15 minutes is optimum for your application?

Comment: Thank you. Without activating a service then I wouldn't be able to run tests like suspend service (unless I use an existing activated service but that relies on the fact that there is already an activated service). Activating a service runs an automated background process which takes 15 minutes.. what do you suggest I should do instead?

Comment: You could look into optimising your background process. Is it necessary to perform all those steps in your test environment? How much data is needed to set up the application? Often tests are performed against a certain amount of test data.